# Ошибка доступа.

Tags: c++

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void main(){
    char*pch="hello";
    char mch[]=" hi";

    cout << strcat(pch, mch) << endl;

    system("pause"); 
};
```

Не пишите про `string`, нужен `char`.

Comment: В C++ не заморачивайтесь с ручным распределением памяти (да, это непросто, надо считать байты), а пользуйтесь std::string:

    int main()
    {
        string pch = "hello";
        string mch = " hi";

        cout << pch + mch << endl;
    };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если внимательно почитать документацию по функции [`strcat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/), то окажется, что первый параметр - буфер, в который будет осуществлена запись результата конкатенации строк. У вас таковым буфером является `pch`. Но объявив его так, ка это сделали вы, вы выделили ровно пять (шесть с нулём-терминатором) байт под этот буфер. Пытаясь приписать к нему ещё три байта вы выходите за границу выделенной памяти, что выливается в segmentation fault. Правильнее было бы выделить заведомо больший объём памяти, вот так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char *str = new char[100];
    char *pch  = "hello";
    char mch[] = " hi";

    strcat(str, pch);
    strcat(str, mch);

    cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Неправильно производится копирование первой подстроки через `strcat`. В области памяти, выделенной с помощью `new`, может находится все, что угодно. `strcat` находит по "целевому" указателю первый символ окончания строки и копирует по нему строку. Но в Вашем варианте в памяти может быть все что угодно! И результат может быть тоже непредсказуемым. 

Поэтому нужно первую подстроку копировать с помощью `strcpy`